# SQLite DB version different from user_version

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am totally confused by the meaning of DB version in my DBadapter and user_version in database Pragma.

I tested using db version=4 then made a back up and opened it in my PC using DB Browser there "SQL PRAGMA user_version" returned 52!

Trying to match versions using "PRAGMA user_version=4" generate a file that would not restore.

A new test using db version=5 showed Pragma user_version 53!

Any debug variants build with db version < 4 would crash.

To use db version=1 I had to build a release variant and uninstall the debug version.

This time the backup file open in DB Browser shows a user_version 49!

Editing user_version of the above backups from 53 to 49 would restore the database fine.

Uninstalling the release variant and back to debug version I could run app with  db version = 1 but user_version was still 49.

Question: how to make user_version match DB version or the other way around so to make restore possible?

Comment: Android's `SQLiteOpenHelper` directly executes `PRAGMA user_version`. What tool do you mean with "DB Browser"? Did you actually execute an SQL command? Are you sure you executed the correct command?

Comment: DB browser for SQLite can be downloaded here http://sqlitebrowser.org/
SQL query:  PRAGMA user_version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: how to make user_version match DB version or the other way
>   around so to make restore possible?

To force the **user_version** use (*before the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass has opened the database*) :-

```
db.setVersion(version);

or via

db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version=" + Integer.toString(version),null);
```

Where db is the respective SQLiteDatabase and version is an int with the DB Version.

Alternately you can override the `onDowngrade` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass, this will then not result in the exception as per :-

> onDowngrade added in API level 11
>
> void onDowngrade (SQLiteDatabase db, 
>                   int oldVersion, 
>                   int newVersion)
>
> Called when the database needs to be downgraded. This is strictly
>   similar to onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) method, but is called
>   whenever current version is newer than requested one. However, this
>   method is not abstract, so it is not mandatory for a customer to
>   implement it. **If not overridden, default implementation will reject
>   downgrade and throws SQLiteException**
>
> This method executes within a transaction. If an exception is thrown,
>   all changes will automatically be rolled back.

The user_version will then be set to the DB Version (if I recall correctly). This does assume that `onUpgrade` has been implemented accordingly.

Comment: By Jove it was all due by this stupid declaration in adapter(from website):    static final int DBVERSION = '1' ; this would set version to the ASCII value of '1' which is integer 49. Likewise '2' is 50 so PRAGMA user_value is set to 49 or 50!! Simply removing quotes and reinstalling app fixed my problem - Thank you so much. BTW i think db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version=" + Integer.toString(version),null); does not need a null

Comment: @alberto oops re null, change it from rawQuery and didn't remove the null.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution it was all due to a silly declaration in DBadapter(from website):

```
 static final int DBVERSION = '1' ; // note single quaotes
```

this would set version to the ASCII value of '1' which is integer 49. Likewise '2' is 50 so PRAGMA user_value is set to 49 or 50!! Simply removing quotes and reinstalling app fixed my problem. Now db version and user_version are the same a crucial factor when restoring the db.